# does result of ORDER BY is always same (SQL Server 2005,2008)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table Item (Id int Primary Key, Number INT) having records

```
Id    Number
100     3
200     3
```

Now I am running a query

```
SELECT I.Id,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY I.Number) RN
FROM Item I
```

in my machine result set is

```
Id   RN
100   1
200   2
```

Now my question is does this result set will be on all machine, OR in some machine it may change as

```
Id   RN
200   1
100   2
```

Any help is welcome

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! Doing so, you don't need any `&nbsp;` and `<br/>` tags anymore, either!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as the undefined order of results mentioned by Panagiotis

The result of `ROW_NUMBER` is undeterministic in the event of ties. You would need to add a tie breaker of a unique column to the `ORDER BY` so that the two rows with `Number=3` have a deterministic numbering applied.

Assuming `Id` is unique the following would be deterministic

```
SELECT I.Id,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY I.Number,I.Id) RN
FROM Item I
ORDER BY RN
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify any ordering for the final result so you don't have any guarantees on how the results will appear.

To order by row number (RN) you should add an ORDER BY RN clause:

```
SELECT I.Id,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY I.Number) RN 
FROM Item I
ORDER BY RN
```

The server doesn't order the results in any specific way unless you request it. This means that the results will appear in the order they are processed by the server.

The server creates an execution plan for each query that may sort data to speed up processing and use different join techniques that may also affect ordering. The form of the execution plan depends on the existence of indexing and the statistics of the tables involved. Finally, the server may use a parallel execution plan in which case partial result sets from different cores are merged in the end.

You will probably never notice this with a simple query, but result order may change even for the same server as data and statistics change with time, resulting in different execution plans.

Comment: And it has NOTHING to do with the sql server version, that is like that in the SQL specifications for 40 years or so. SQL is SET based, sets have no intrinsic order.

Answer (score 0):

The result set may be any of:

```
Id        RN
100        1
200        2
```

or,

```
Id        RN
200        1
100        2
```

or,

```
Id        RN
100        2
200        1
```

or,

```
Id        RN
200        2
100        1
```

The rules of SQL are very simple - if you *want* a specific ordering, you have to ask for it. If you *incompletely* specify an ordering, then the system is free to arrange rows in any order it finds most convenient, so long as it conforms to the specification you *have* given it.

If you want to force a specific ordering, specify it completely. E.g. if you want the first result always, specify `ORDER BY I.Number,I.Id` and have that both within the `ROW_NUMBER` specification and as the `ORDER BY` clause.